# Missing mail when send mail using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook`

Tags: c#, email, outlook

When sending mail using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook`,
sometimes the mail is missing.

It is confirmed that no exception occurred in the code, and the method inside the `Send` event worked normally.

However, sometimes when the mail cannot be found in the sent items of OUTLOOK and the client does not receive the mail either.

These days, the frequency of occurrence of this problem has increased.

Because there is a log in the `DbInsert` method, it is clear that the user sent the mail.

I couldn't find the cause, so I first updated the version of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` from `15.0.4797.1003` to `15.0.4797.1004`, but I am not sure that this is the cause.

It's not a firewall or spam problem either. If check that the mail is missing and send it again with the same program, I can see that it has been sent without missing it.

please help me

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

        public void sendMail(string sampleBody) {
            Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();


            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            
            mailItem.HTMLBody = sampleBody;

            ((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)mailItem).Send += (ref bool b) => {
                DbInsert(); //method works fine
            };



            try {
                 mailItem.Send();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                 MessageBox.Show("Err! : " + e.Message);
                 mailItem.Display(true);
            }
        }
```